# Proof of Herglotz Theorem in Time Series Analysis

Tags: time-series, fourier-transform, spectral-analysis

I am studying time series, following Time Series Theory and Methods by Brockwell and Davis. I am reading the proof of the Herglotz Theorem, I have the following questions.

First, the proof given in the book is the next one:

[image]

I don´t understand the equality given in the proof (I drew an arrow there) 
 How to get $\frac{1}{2\pi N}\displaystyle\sum_{|m|-N}(N-|m|)e^{imv}\gamma(v)$

Aditionally, I don't have clear why is possible to say that $f_N(.)I_{(-\pi,\pi]}$ is a density function?

I add the part where is mentioned that $f_N$ is a density, I don´t have clear why it is true.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's something similar to the *change of variable* trick in integration. The two expressions in the text clearly indicate you to consider substituting $r - s$ with $m$. The details are spelled out as follows.

For simplicity, let's denote the summand $e^{-i(r - s)v}\gamma(r - s)$ by a bivariate function $K(r, s)$, whose domain is the set of $N \times N$ grid points $\{1, 2, \ldots, N\} \times \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$. On the other hand, note that $K(r, s)$ is completely determined by the coordinate differences $m := r - s$, therefore may also be denoted by $\tilde{K}(m)$. The challenge is to express the double sum $S := \sum_{r = 1}^N \sum_{s = 1}^N K(r, s)$ in terms of the new summing index $m$. I will illustrate this transformation process in matrix form as follows.

In terms of $(r, s)$, we are effectively summing over the matrix (think the row corresponds to $r$ and the column corresponds to $s$):
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
K(1, 1) & K(1, 2) & \cdots & K(1, N) \\
K(2, 1) & K(2, 2) & \cdots & K(2, N) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
K(N, 1) & K(N, 2) & \cdots & K(N, N)
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{1}
\end{align}

As stated before, since $K(r, s) = \tilde{K}(r - s) = \tilde{K}(m)$, matrix 
$(1)$ is equal to 
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\tilde{K}(0) & \tilde{K}(-1) & \cdots & \tilde{K}(1 - N) \\
\tilde{K}(1) & \tilde{K}(0) & \cdots & \tilde{K}(2 - N) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\tilde{K}(N - 1) & \tilde{K}(N - 2) & \cdots & \tilde{K}(0)
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

The entries in matrix $(2)$ can be summed over diagonally. For example, there are $N$ terms $\tilde{K}(0)$ lie on the main diagonal line, which corresponds to $m = 0$. There are $N - 1$ terms of $\tilde{K}(-1)$ and 
$\tilde{K}(1)$ lie on the first off-diagonal line of the upper triangle and that of the lower triangle, which correspond to $m = -1$ and $m = 1$, respectively. In general, on the $m$-th off-diagonal line of the upper triangle, there are $N - m$ terms of $\tilde{K}(-m)$, while on the $m$-th 
off-diagonal line of the lower triangle, there are $N - m$ terms of $\tilde{K}(m)$. Summing all the $N^2$ terms of $\tilde{K}(\cdot)$ in this way, we obtain
\begin{align}
S = & \sum_{\text{upper triangle}} \tilde{K}(\cdot) + \sum_{\text{diagonal}}\tilde{K}(\cdot) + \sum_{\text{lower triangle}}\tilde{K}(\cdot) \\
= & \sum_{m = 1}^{N - 1} (N - m)\tilde{K}(-m) + N\tilde{K}(0) + \sum_{m = 1}^{N - 1}(N - m)\tilde{K}(m) \\
= & \sum_{|m| < N} (N - |m|)\tilde{K}(m).
\end{align}

This completes the proof.

For your second question, to show $f_N(\cdot)I_{(-\pi, \pi]}(\cdot)$ is a density function, since $f_N(v) \geq 0$ for all $v \in (-\pi, \pi]$, it suffices to show that 
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_N(v) dv = 1.$$

By the identity we just proved, together with the linearity of the integral,
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f_N(v) dv = \frac{1}{2\pi N}\sum_{|m| < N} (N - |m|)\gamma(m) \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{imv} dv.$$

It is easy to show (also well-known as the orthogonality of Fourier basis) that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{imv} dv = \begin{cases}
0 & m \neq 0, \\
2\pi & m = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Combining this with the fact $\gamma(0) = 1$, it follows that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f_N(v) dv = 1$.

PS: I found your question is more about pure mathematical derivation, which may be more appropriate to be asked at Mathematics Stack Exchange. Indeed, this time series book you are reading is written in a very rigorous way.

Comment: Zhanxiong, but I added the part where is mentioned that $f_N(.)$ is a density function. My question is how to affirm that?.

Comment: Additionally, if this book is written in a very rigorous way, could you recommend me a book simpler, in order to understand some of the concepts. I am following this book in my lecture because the professor follos this book, But sometimes is really hard to understand most of the concepts given.

Comment: @Boris I will edit my answer. To answer your recommendation question, what level are you in? Undergraduate or graduate?

Comment: Zhanxiong, I am graduate student, this lecture is part of my master in statistics.

Comment: OK. Then I would recommend Ruey Tsay's book *Analysis of Financial Time Series*. The accessibility (in terms of mathematics maturity) is much easier than your current book while it explains basic concepts well, which also covers more applied models. Hope it helps and good luck to your studies.

Comment: By the way, I am not sure if here is Ok to ask you for a recommendation of a book of multivariate statistics, more simpler, the notes of my course part of the master also are very theoretical I need a good reference more practical, specially the chapter of Estimators of Location and Scatter, M functionals and M-estimators, Analysis of discriminant and classification. That we have been studying most of the theoretical aspects.

Comment: It looks like your master-level curriculum is even more demanding than phd-level's. I don't think any applied multivariate text would cover M-estimators and M-functionals. For a more conventional route, you may check [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Applied-Multivariate-Statistical-Analysis-6th/dp/0131877151).

Comment: @Zhanxiong: I've been annoying myself recently by trying to understand  Herglotz theorem and I only recently found your amazing explanation. The change to a single sum totally puzzled me until I found your golden insight. Thank you so much.

Comment: If anyone ever reads this in the future, I think another text that a reader may prefer rather than Brockwell and Davis is "Time Series Analysis" by Hamilton. It also can be  pretty theoretical at times but atleast the details behind the derivations tend to be shown. B&D is well  known for its terse explanations.  At the same time, it's breadth of coverage is impressive. Hamilton gears itself more towards an "econometric" viewpoint as opposed to a "mathematical" viewpoint.