# Why is $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} Cov(X_i,X_j) = \sum_{i-j=-n}^{n} (n-|i-j|)\gamma(i-j)$ for a stationary time series

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity

My book presents the following derivation of the variance of the mean estimator $\bar{X_n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$ for a stationary process $(X_t)_{t}$ with autocovariance function $\gamma(\cdot)$:
[image]

I do not understand the last equality in the calculation above. Could someone explain how they have rewritten the sum (from summing over $i,j$ to summing over $i-j$) and why there is factor $n-|i-j|$ multiplied with the autocovariance function?

Comment: What is the property of covariance in stationary process? What does it have to do with lags? Can you relate the summation now?

Comment: Check the trick in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322020/proof-of-herglotz-theorem-in-time-series-analysis/322026#322026).  Basically it is about how to rearrange the order of summation -- originally the sum (the penultimate expression) is taken by rows/columns, and it was rearranged to sum over diagonal/sub-diagonal lines (the last expression).